# sup tag doesnt work inside title tag

Tags: html, css

I have a sup tag in a title tag and it does not work but will work in a li tag. Anyone know why? I can change the title tags out to H class but its bugging me to know. Here is what I have:

```
<ul>
  <title>TPC <sup>®</sup></title>
  <li>TPC<sup>®</sup></li>
  <li>TPC<sup>®</sup></li>
  <li>TPC<sup>®</sup></li>

</ul>
```

The sup works fine in all the li tags but not the title. In the title it displays the actual code as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`title`**](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html) element is used only to set the title of the document, which you'll generally see in the browser's tab.

Only `li` elements are allowed as direct children of the `ul` element.

If you're hoping to style the page's title, you're out of luck.  [**Only text can be used**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-title-element) within the `title` element.

---

If you'd simply like to style the first item in a list differently, you can do something like this:

```css
li:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>TPC<sup>®</sup></li>
  <li>TPC<sup>®</sup></li>
  <li>TPC<sup>®</sup></li>
  <li>TPC<sup>®</sup></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I did a title there, made a rookie mistake and must have been not thinking. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (okay, technically *shouldn't*) use `title` tags anywhere other than in the `head` tag, and there should only be one `title` tag in a document. A `ul` tag definitely cannot have a `title` tag as a direct child; only an `li` tag is appropriate there.

So, the short answer to your question is: **don't do this.** It's not supposed to work, so it probably won't.

You can [read more here](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html).

Answer (score 1):

Title tag is used within `<head></head>` not within `<body></body>`